# Why am I unable to access the window.scrollY value of a webpage using a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, content-script

I'm writing a chrome extension in js to grab some data from a webpage and I need to get the window.scrollY property, however on [the website im trying to scrape](https://tellonym.me/tells) it always returns 0.

The only way I've been able to even come close is this:

```js
function getScrollY() {
  var actualCode = 'console.log(window.scrollY)';

  document.documentElement.setAttribute('onreset', actualCode);
  document.documentElement.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('reset'));
  document.documentElement.removeAttribute('onreset');
}
```

This correctly prints the window.scrollY to console but I'm unable to actually return that value, only console.log it and so it is useless.

Trying to use window.scrollY directly always returns 0:

[image]

The first and last 2 lines are just to show that scrollY is set to a non-zero value, and the line with "0" from TellScrape.js is the result of `console.log(window.scrollY)` in my content script.

A snippit of the code where it's used:

```js
async function startScraping() {
  // Keep track of the span elements we've already added
  const spanElementsProcessed = new Set();

  const spanTexts = [];

  var textCountElement = document.createElement("p");
  textCountElement.style.fontSize = "15px";
  textCountElement.style.color = "gray";
  textCountElement.whiteSpace = "pre";
  countElement.appendChild(textCountElement);

  //this is where the "0" is coming from in the screenshot
  console.log(window.scrollY);

  // Keep scrolling until we reach the top of the page
  while (window.scrollY) {
    await new Promise(setTimeout);
    // Find all divs
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
    textCountElement.textContent = "Current scroll: " + window.scrollY + "\r\nCurrent scraped: " + spanTexts.length + "\r\nCurrent unique: " + [...new Set(spanTexts)].length;
    //these console.logs will eventually be removed but are here for debugging
    console.log("Current scroll: " + window.scrollY);
    console.log("Current scraped: " + spanTexts.length);
    console.log("Current unique: " + [...new Set(spanTexts)].length);

    // Check for any "show more" divs and expand them
    for (var div of divs) {
      if (div.textContent === 'show more') {
        div.click();
      }
    }

    // Get all span elements on the page
    var spans = document.querySelectorAll("span");

    // Loop through the elements and replace newline characters with ¶
    for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
      var spanE = spans[i];
      spanE.textContent = spanE.textContent.replace(/\n/g, "¶");
    }

    // Now find all the span elements
    const spanElements = document.querySelectorAll('span');

    // Add every new span element's textcontent into spanTexts
    for (const span of spanElements) {
      if (!spanElementsProcessed.has(span)) {
        spanElementsProcessed.add(span);
        spanTexts.push(span.textContent);
      }
    }
    // Wait 100 milliseconds before continuing the loop
    await sleep(100);
  }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `window.scrollY` can be used directly in the content script, it's not related to "clean" view of the window object, so the problem in your case is caused by something else. Show us how you execute the content script and how getScrollY is called.

Comment: @wOxxOm ```window.scrollY``` always returns 0 whenever I use it in my content script (researching this it seems to be for security?), no matter where I am scrolled on the page - using the browser console however it returns the scrollY correctly. I mostly need this because I have a while loop with the condition ```window.scrollY !== 0```.

Comment: This is a standard property which is not related to security and it works properly for me (and always has been working) in a content script, which is why the only explanation I see is that the problem is elsewhere. It may be caused by a variety of reasons like the wrong timing, the wrong way to do the loop (it must be asynchronous).

Comment: @wOxxOm i'm pretty much a complete beginner to js. The ```window.scrollY``` is only accessed within an async function (if thats what that means). The script works fine if I simply paste the code into the js console.

Comment: The fact that it prints in console correctly only indicates that the loop is incorrectly organized. Please show how you call getScrollY and the loop so we don't go in circles.

Comment: Here's an example of a correct loop: `while (window.scrollY) { await new Promise(setTimeout) }`

Comment: @wOxxOm using getScrollY was just a way to try and get around the fact that window.scrollY always gave 0. The function I provided does not return anything, only console.log's window.scrollY from the onreset event. Normally (from the browser console) I was just using window.scrollY directly, so my while loop was ```while (window.scrollY){//code here}``` EDIT: within the while loop there is also ```console.log(window.scrollY)``` if that helps/makes a difference.

Comment: The correct loop must be asynchronous i.e. it should use `await` + `setTimeout`  as shown in my comment above or it should be a function callback of setInterval/setTimeout.

Comment: Suggested reading: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: @ThomasMueller any better?

Comment: @wOxxOm I've added the code to my post where this is used.

Comment: @Peter --- Yes, it's much better, but I still can't reproduce the problem. See my comment on NorioYamamoto's answer.

Answer (score 1):

My test results contradict your claims.

**No scroll.**
[image]

**With scroll.**
[image]

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "content_scripts",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "matches.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

matches.js

```js
console.log("window.scrollY=" + window.scrollY)
```

Comment: [Here's my results](https://imgur.com/OnKtSwt), the first and last two lines are me showing the scrollY is correct. the line with the "0" called from TellScrape.js is the result of ```console.log(window.scrollY)```

Comment: @Peter --- With NorioYamamoto's code, I also get a non-zero value for `window.scrollY`. We need to know the URL of the web page you're scraping. If it's a website that only you can access, then I'm afraid it's the end of the line for me. Also, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be very helpful, because we don't know when and how you're injecting the content script into the web page.

Comment: @ThomasMueller I tested it on another webpage and it seemed to work fine. The site is https://tellonym.me/tells, however you need an account. Not sure what this could mean.

Comment: @Novet --- "The site is tellonym.me/tells" --- Now that you've mentioned this minor detail, I can reproduce the problem. However, I have no idea what causes it. Maybe it's because the website uses Javascript to update what it's displaying? Which brings us back to the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) that I mentioned earlier. Why are you using "window.scrollY is zero" as the terminating condition for your while-loop?